# Hundreds number of rows in a grid leads to a gap at the bottom

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I noticed that when the number of rows in a grid exceeds a few hundreds, some gap at the bottom is appeared sometimes. More rows doesn't mean more gap at the bottom. For example, in the following example there is a little gap at the end, but if you try to increase the number of rows from 1100 to 1300, this gap disappears (1400 – it appears again). How to avoid it?

Yes, I can use absolute positioning, but in this case I should re-render UI components with absolute positioning each time the window size is changed. The reason why I need so many rows is that I want to divide one day into minutes and put events so way when the user changes the browser size, the size of events will be changed also without re-rendering UI components. It would be great if it's possible to solve this problem using grid somehow.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      #grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(1100, 1fr);
        height: 100vh;
      }
      #container {
        grid-row: 900 / span 200;
        background-color: gray;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='grid'>
      <div id='container'>
        Container
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Example]

P.S. Seems that everything works fine. I've made a mistake. `grid-row` should be equal to `901`, not `900` in the following example. Yes, the chrome shows some gap at the bottom (I don't know why), but the grid has full height.

Comment: Dividing a day into minutes for tracking purposes is very rarely done. No one is really interested in tracking with that level of detail. At best this is usually done with a minimum of 15 minute chunks. You might want to rethink your approach.

Comment: you may lay down your UI in 15min chunks, as @Pauli_D suggests, and then let the user fine tune the time

Comment: I disagree. It should be possible to set an event at 10:10 for the user (the flight may depart at 00:01). This events can be shown in the UI just at 10:00 (or 10:15) and 00:00 respectively, but it's not a good approach. Let's imagine we have 2 events that start at 10:00 and 10:10. If both of them will be placed at 10:00, the user can't see that the second one starts slightly later than the first one. I've created this 2 events in the MacOS calendar (day is divided into minutes) and I can see in the UI that the second event starts later than the first one.

Comment: But I agree that it's not necessary to divide a day into minutes, 5 minutes is enough. In spite of this, we can divide a day into minutes and it also works. I had a mistake in `grid-row`.

Comment: If you want such fine details, use a `<canvas>` instead.